# Delphi Component displayed wrong when running

Tags: delphi, runtime, components

I'm using Delhi XE2 to create a custom progressbar Component. I thought I had it working, but if I run an application with the progressbar, the complete layout changes.
The red, yellow and black panels disappear and only the (main) green one is visible.

Here is my code:

```
unit CustomProgressBar;

interface

uses
System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TCustomProgresBar = class(TPanel)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    LeftRedPanel: TPanel;
    LeftYellowPanel: TPanel;
    RightRedPanel: TPanel;
    RightYellowPanel: TPanel;
    BlackPanel: TPanel;
    function GetLeftRedPanelWidth: Integer;
    procedure SetLeftRedPanelWidth(const NewWidth: Integer);
    function GetLeftYellowPanelWidth: Integer;
    procedure SetLeftYellowPanelWidth(const NewWidth: Integer);
    function GetRightRedPanelWidth: Integer;
    procedure SetRightRedPanelWidth(const NewWidth: Integer);
    function GetRightYellowPanelWidth: Integer;
    procedure SetRightYellowPanelWidth(const NewWidth: Integer);
    function GetPosition: Integer;
    procedure SetPosition(const NewPosition: Integer);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property LeftRedPanelWidth: integer read GetLeftRedPanelWidth write SetLeftRedPanelWidth;
    property LeftYellowPanelWidth: integer read GetLeftYellowPanelWidth write SetLeftYellowPanelWidth;
    property RightRedPanelWidth: integer read GetRightRedPanelWidth write SetRightRedPanelWidth;
property RightYellowPanelWidth: integer read GetRightYellowPanelWidth write SetRightYellowPanelWidth;
    property Position: integer read GetPosition write SetPosition;
  end;



procedure Register;

implementation

procedure TCustomProgresBar.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  BlackPanel.Height:=Height;
end;


function TCustomProgresBar.GetLeftRedPanelWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := LeftRedPanel.Width;
end;

procedure TCustomProgresBar.SetLeftRedPanelWidth(const NewWidth: Integer);
begin
  if NewWidth <> LeftRedPanel.Width then
  begin
    LeftRedPanel.Width := NewWidth;
    Invalidate; // redraws the component
  end;
end;

function TCustomProgresBar.GetLeftYellowPanelWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := LeftYellowPanel.Width;
end;

procedure TCustomProgresBar.SetLeftYellowPanelWidth(const NewWidth: Integer);
begin
  if NewWidth <> LeftYellowPanel.Width then
  begin
    LeftYellowPanel.Width := NewWidth;
    Invalidate; // redraws the component
  end;
end;

function TCustomProgresBar.GetRightRedPanelWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := RightRedPanel.Width;
end;

procedure TCustomProgresBar.SetRightRedPanelWidth(const NewWidth: Integer);
begin
  if NewWidth <> RightRedPanel.Width then
  begin
    RightRedPanel.Width := NewWidth;
    Invalidate; // redraws the component
  end;
end;

function TCustomProgresBar.GetRightYellowPanelWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := RightYellowPanel.Width;
end;

procedure TCustomProgresBar.SetRightYellowPanelWidth(const NewWidth: Integer);
begin
  if NewWidth <> RightYellowPanel.Width then
  begin
    RightYellowPanel.Width := NewWidth;
    Invalidate; // redraws the component
  end;
end;

function TCustomProgresBar.GetPosition: Integer;
begin
  Result := BlackPanel.Left;
end;

procedure TCustomProgresBar.SetPosition(const NewPosition: Integer);
begin
  if NewPosition <> BlackPanel.Left then
  begin
    BlackPanel.Left := NewPosition;
    Invalidate; // redraws the component
  end;
end;


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MarcelS', [TCustomProgresBar]);

end;

constructor TCustomProgresBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited create(Aowner);
  Color:=65280;  //Green
  Width:=200;
  Height:=25;
  BevelOuter:=bvNone;

  LeftRedPanel:=TPanel.Create(Self);
  with LeftRedPanel do
  begin
    Parent := Self;
    Align:=alLeft;
    Color:=255;    //Red
    Width:=25;
    Caption:='';
    BevelOuter:=bvNone;
  end;

  LeftYellowPanel:=TPanel.Create(Self);
  with LeftYellowPanel do
  begin
    Parent := Self;
    Align:=alLeft;
    Color:=65535;   //Yellow
    Width:=25;
    Caption:='';
    BevelOuter:=bvNone;
  end;

  RightYellowPanel:=TPanel.Create(Self);
  with RightYellowPanel do
  begin
    Parent := Self;
    Align:=alRight;
    Color:=65535;   //Yellow
    Width:=25;
    Caption:='';
    BevelOuter:=bvNone;
  end;

  RightRedPanel:=TPanel.Create(Self);
  with RightRedPanel do
  begin
    Parent := Self;
    Align:=alRight;
    Color:=255;   //Red
    Width:=25;
    Caption:='';
    BevelOuter:=bvNone;
  end;

  BlackPanel:=TPanel.Create(Self);
  with BlackPanel do
  begin
    Parent := Self;
    Align:=alNone;
    Color:=0;   //Red
    Width:=5;
    Left:=35;
    Caption:='';

    Top:=0;
    BevelOuter:=bvNone;
  end;

  BlackPanel.Height:=Height;
  Caption:='';
end;

end.
```

Comment: You are on the wrong path. You should have paint whatever you needed in the overriden `Paint` method. Not make a bunch of *child* controls inside a container. You wouldn't have this problem with such approach.

Comment: I am not sure what the purpose of  this progressbar is. Do you want a progressbar where the user can choose color or what ? If all you need is to show in another color or another layout than why all these panels ? Just paint different. If there really is a need for the panels then please edit your question to make that clear for us.

Comment: @TLama is quite right. Your current approach is complex, very hard to get right, and positively invites flicker. Just paint the control.

Comment: As @TLama said you don't need multiple child controls and should override the `Paint` method to do your control drawing. You could even draw your progress bar on a `TGraphicControl` but having lots of child controls is the wrong approach.

Comment: And if you go that wrong way.. then choose better TCustomPanel.. and not TPanel ;)

Comment: @ZEN only to derive from. The sub components would be TPanel if not published.

Comment: Of course.. that's what I thought. Deriving from TPanel is not a good way..

Comment: This could be as easy as `Canvas.Rectangle(R)` where R is a `TRect` with the calculated points where to draw the rectangle.

Comment: The problem is not in this component code, it is in the calling/managing code.

Comment: I threw together a sample to get you on the right track: http://pastebin.com/KnTcrmWB

Comment: @Jerry, better ask if the value is the same as the field value and only if not update the field and invalidate the control, but that code is essentially correct (even though far away from the layout presented here).

Comment: @TLama Indeed, just giving OP starting grounds to understand how they *should* be designing it, as opposed to embedding controls. Otherwise I would have posted it as an answer :-) Besides, the `Invalidate` process in VCL doesn't necessarily repaint immediately at least. It just flags the message queue to let it know it needs to be redrawn.

Comment: Only just now did I realize "progress" was mis-spelled. I relied on copy-paste to structure tht class, based on the class name of OP in this question.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your support! I think I know now had to go forward. Not with the panels... Also thanks for the sample of Jerry. To clarify, my idea is to make a progressbar/gauge component with a red (problem) area at for example 0-10% for minimum values and 90 to 100% for maximum values. Also a yellow (warning) area at for example 10 to 20% and 80 to 90%. The idea is that a user will be able to see if the value is good, needs attention (yellow) or will give a problem (red). The size of the red and yellow area's need to be adjustable.

Comment: This is what I made: [link](http://pastebin.com/uG6fZ2kZ). I tested it and this does what I want. I only think the last Canvas (Needle) can also be done with a line but I don't know how at the moment. Your example was very helpfull @JerryDodge! Is this the right way?